# Why does drupal_lookup_path() return NULL?

Tags: path-aliases, testing

In a Drupal 7 site, I installed the Pathauto module. The user account I am using to log in has the permission to create new path aliases.

When I manually create a node, unselect the checkbox for automatic alias generation, and enter a custom alias (for example, *qwerty*), I can use `drupal_lookup_path()` to get the path alias.

```php
$path = drupal_lookup_path('node/' . $node->nid);
```

However, using the following code in a test doesn't work.

```php
$edit = array(
  'title' => 'asdf',
  'path[alias]' => 'qwerty',
);
$this->drupalPost("node/add/{$this->content_type}", $edit, t('Save'));

$path = drupal_lookup_path('node/' . $node->nid);
```

The value of `$path` is `NULL`, even when the path alias exists and `$this->drupalGet('qwerty')` returns a 200 status.

Why is `drupal_lookup_path()` failing to find the path alias only when called from a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked this down to the fact that `current_path()`, which returns `path/to/content` in the browser, instead returns `batch` when called from within Simpletest.

Since `drupal_lookup_path()` uses the output of `current_path()` to generate the `$cache[map]` variable that it uses to find and store the path alias, this prevents `drupal_lookup_path()` from working in tests.

I have filed this as [an issue on d.o](http://drupal.org/node/1903740).